# Get-only property with constant value, auto-property or not?

Tags: c#, properties

Is there a performance/memory usage difference between the two following property declarations, and should one be preferred?

```
public bool Foo => true;

public bool Foo { get; } = true;
```

Also, does the situation change if the Boolean is replaced with a different immutable value (e.g. string)?

Comment: The first example always returns `true`. The second example just sets a default value. If you later add a `set` accessor then it may no longer return `true`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wrote this class as an example

```
class Program
{
    public bool A => true;
    public bool B { get; } = true;
}
```

with reflection I decompiled the assembly and get this code

```
class Program
{
    // Fields
    [CompilerGenerated, DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)]
    private readonly bool <B>k__BackingField = true;

    public bool A
    {
        get
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public bool B
    {
        [CompilerGenerated]
        get
        {
            return this.<B>k__BackingField;
        }
    }
}
```

So as @Fruchtzwerg mentioned both ways have the same way to return the value **BUT** the difference is in the implementation of getter methods since one return the value `ture` and the other return a field which has the value `true`.

Talking about performance and memory the first way seems to be better, but if you only need this property to be `true` I suggest to use `const` .

Comment: Thank you and @Fruchtzwerg. Just to note, I need it to be a property for WPF binding purposes.

Comment: @CallumWatkins if you need it to be a property, the first one I think is better since it doesn't have a backing filed

Comment: It seems to me that Arvin is correct here, that even though the property is accessed in the same way, the compiled getter methods are different. Fruchtzwerg is not wrong per se, but they only show one side of the story.

Answer (score 3):

I created a simple example to show the difference. I created the two classes `A` and `B` with the different property implementations.

```
public class A
{
    public bool Foo => true;
}

public class B
{
    public bool Foo { get; } = true;
}
```

A simple test code using the classes should be enought to show the differences at the generated CIL code:

```
A a = new A();
B b = new B();

bool c;
c = a.Foo;
c = b.Foo;
```

Disassembly is showing the following code:

```
            c = a.Foo;
00C50FB0  mov         ecx,dword ptr [ebp-40h]  
00C50FB3  cmp         dword ptr [ecx],ecx  
00C50FB5  call        00C50088  
00C50FBA  mov         dword ptr [ebp-54h],eax  
00C50FBD  movzx       eax,byte ptr [ebp-54h]  
00C50FC1  mov         dword ptr [ebp-48h],eax  
            c = b.Foo;
00C50FC4  mov         ecx,dword ptr [ebp-44h]  
00C50FC7  cmp         dword ptr [ecx],ecx  
00C50FC9  call        00C500A8  
00C50FCE  mov         dword ptr [ebp-58h],eax  
00C50FD1  movzx       eax,byte ptr [ebp-58h]  
00C50FD5  mov         dword ptr [ebp-48h],eax
```

This means there is **no difference** (except the getter in line 3 --> Have a look at @Arvins answer). Also changing the type is resulting in exactly the same CIL code at both implementations.

Comment: the structures are the same, but the difference is in the implementation of the getter method which is called in line 3

Comment: The difference is that the `=> true` is an expression that is evaluated every time it is used. In this case you're returning a constant and the IL will be simplified to look exactly like the second case, which is using a readonly backing field and just sets its value at init time, and getting it just reads it.